# How to pass variable from PowerApp to HTTP step of the PowerApp flow?

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to set a global variable inside the PowerApp application by using:

```
Set(barcodeStr,BarcodeScanner.Value)
```

After that, I want to pass a value of that variable to Power App Flow to use that string to construct a URL for sending a GET request to some server.

Am I on the right way to do that with the following steps:

[image]

When I try to manually insert a hardcoded string I get a response from the server that is correct, but I want to do that dynamically passing the variable from Power App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'initialize variable' step, if you click on the value text input, you should see an option for the dynamic content to get the value from Power Apps:

[image]

Once that is done, you save the flow, and add it in Power Apps, you will have the ability to pass that value to the flow, something like

```
YourFlowName.Run(barcodeStr)
```